# Get error when call angular2 function inside jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

When I call the function inside jQuery i get the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: this.getSelectedItem is not a function",

Does anyone know how to call this function without error? 
Thanks for help

```
getSelectedItem(selected: string) {
  this.currentValueSelectedItem = selected;
  this.selectedItem = selected;
  var foundItem = this.currentCollection.find(x => x.innerHTML === selected);
  this.fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(foundItem).getPropertyValue("font-size");
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('#designedPage').load(function () {
    var iframe = $('#designedPage').contents();
    iframe.find("body").click(function (event: any) {            
      this.getSelectedItem(event.target.innerHTML); //here I get error
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the lambda notation to maintain the `this` context. Besides the idea that using `jQuery` like this in angular is quite frowned upon:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('#designedPage').load(() => {
    var iframe = $('#designedPage').contents();
    iframe.find("body").click((event: any) => {
       this.getSelectedItem(event.target.innerHTML); //here I get error
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: @James you obviously have to change it in the `load` handler as well. Rule of thumb, never use the keyword `function` within angular, not until you figure out what it does :). I've updated my answer

Comment: It's old, but I guess it might help some : Yes, using `Jquery` with Angular is kind of the pokerface, but there are times when you can't do without...
For example, I never found any drag & drop angular library that allowed me to replicate the Jquery-UI `draggable` and `sortable` mechanisms.